# Getting Imageview added programmatically

Tags: android

I’m trying to move along the screen an ImageView that was added programmatically. To do so

I’m searching its id through getIdentifier. Should this work? Code bellow:

```
int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("lemon1", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pos =   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
pos.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
image.setLayoutParams(pos);
```

How should I proceed to achieve what I’m intending to do?

Comment: If you have programmatically added an `ImageView`, don't you have it as a variable somewhere?

Comment: what @Zabri said. if you added it, keep a reference to it yourself. beyond that, we'd need to see how you added it. did you set an ID on the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In your first line you're getting the ID of a drawable, **not** of the `ImageView`. You need to get the ID of the `ImageView` itself. If you've programmatically created/added the `ImageView` you'll also need to [programmatically set the ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) if you want to use `findViewById` to get it again. Alternatively you could keep a reference to the actual `View`.

Comment: @Javanes Great, glad to be of help. If this is answered to your satisfaction, go ahead and mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the side. Also feel free to click the triangle to upvote if you've found this answer useful!